# Userform to change the column width and row height

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a userform containing 2 textboxes, 4 different check boxes, 4 radial buttons and 2 command buttons, as seen below:

[image: Userform]

I want to change the row and column widths in the active sheet, or all the worksheets in a workbook, based on the selections in the form.

**Frames**

1. - TextBox1 (Column Width), TextBox2 (Row Height)
   - To type the row height and column width.
2. - Optionbutton1 (Column B onwards) , OptionButton2 (Column C onwards)
   - To select from which Column (B or C) you want to change the column width.
3. - Optionbutton3 (Selected Sheet), OptionButton4 (All sheets)
   - To select on which sheet you want to change the row height and column width ( On Active sheet or On All the sheets).
4. - CheckBox1 (Cover) , CheckBox2 (Trans_Letter), CheckBox3 (Abbreviations) CheckBox3 (Sheet ending with _Index)
   - One check box each for 4 of the sheets in my workbook. There are ~50 sheets in my workbook, these check boxes are for selecting which sheets to *exclude* while changing the column width and row height, when changing all of the sheets.

---

Please find below the code which I have put in the userform.

I am getting error on this line:

```
If IsError(WorksheetFunction.Match(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetNumber).Name, sheetsToExcludeArray, 0)) Then
```

> Error Message: Run Time error '1004' Unable to get the Match property
>   of the worksheet function

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    
    Dim startColumn As Long    
    Dim formatAllSheets As Boolean    
    Dim sheetsToExcludeList As String    
    Dim sheetNumber As Long    
    startColumn = 3
    If Me.OptionButton1.Value Then startColumn = 2    
    formatAllSheets = True    
    If Me.OptionButton3.Value Then formatAllSheets = False

    If Me.CheckBox1.Value Then sheetsToExcludeList = sheetsToExcludeList & ",Cover"
    If Me.CheckBox2.Value Then sheetsToExcludeList = sheetsToExcludeList & ",Trans_Letter"
    If Me.CheckBox3.Value Then sheetsToExcludeList = sheetsToExcludeList & ",Abbreviations"
    If Me.CheckBox4.Value Then sheetsToExcludeList = sheetsToExcludeList & ",Index"
    sheetsToExcludeList = Mid(sheetsToExcludeList, 2)

    Dim lastRow As Long    
    Dim lastColumn As Long    
    Dim itemInArray As Long    
    Dim rangeToFormat As Range    
    Dim sheetsToExcludeArray As Variant  

    If startColumn < 2 Or startColumn > 3 Then startColumn = 2
    sheetsToExcludeArray = Split(sheetsToExcludeList, ",")

    If formatAllSheets Then    
        For sheetNumber = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count    
            If LBound(sheetsToExcludeArray) <= UBound(sheetsToExcludeArray) Then
                If IsError(WorksheetFunction.Match(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetNumber).Name, sheetsToExcludeArray, 0)) Then         
                    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetNumber)                   
                        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row                
                        lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column                 
                        Set rangeToFormat = .Range(.Cells(1, startColumn), .Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))                 
                        rangeToFormat.Cells.RowHeight = me.textbox1.value
                        rangeToFormat.Cells.ColumnWidth = me.textbox2.value
                    End With    
                End If
            Else
                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetNumber)               
                    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row                
                    lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column             
                    Set rangeToFormat = .Range(.Cells(1, startColumn), .Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))             
                    rangeToFormat.Cells.RowHeight = me.textbox1.value
                    rangeToFormat.Cells.ColumnWidth = me.texbox2.value
                End With    
            End If    
        Next sheetNumber    
    Else 
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetNumber)       
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row        
            lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column     
            Set rangeToFormat = .Range(.Cells(1, startColumn), .Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))     
            rangeToFormat.Cells.RowHeight = me.textbox1.value
            rangeToFormat.Cells.ColumnWidth = me.textbox2.value     
        End With    
    End If    
End Sub
```

Comment: *Please suggest.* .... Uhm, suggest what, exactly? (I do suggest reading how to create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can actually help you with the issue you face).

Comment: Actually this code is not working so if you could guide me as to what have I done incorrectly would really appreciate

Comment: I have attached the userform as well to give more insight

Comment: Stacey - once again I point you to the link I referenced. I don't think many people will have the time or interest to poor through that long block of code and recreate the UserForm to find the source of your error when you have not shown any effort you have made to do the same.

Comment: `sheetsToExcludeArray` is a Variant data type. `Match` expects a `Range` object for the 2nd argument.

Comment: Try this instead: `If Instr(sheetsToExcludeList, ThisWorkbook(Worksheets(sheetNumber).Name) = 0`

Comment: I am getting syntax error with the above statement

Comment: sorry ... `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`

Comment: Now its not giving any error but when I am clicking on Add/Event, nothing is happening

Comment: please debug the code line-by-line and submit another question or update this one with a more clear problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, this answer uses an adaptation of the sub `resizerowscols`, which I wrote to answer your more recent question: [Change column width and row height of hidden columns and rows (remaining hidden): Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43714024/change-column-width-and-row-height-of-hidden-columns-and-rows-remaining-hidden/43716727?noredirect=1#comment74478322_43716727)

---

**Main Click Sub**

This (untested) sub takes the values from the form, then loops through the sheets (or just uses active sheet) and calls the other sub to do the resizing.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' Frame 1 values
    Dim colwidth As Double
    colwidth = Me.TextBox1.Value
    Dim rowheight As Double
    rowheight = Me.TextBox2.Value
    ' Frame 2 values
    Dim selectedCol As String
    If Me.OptionButton1.Value = True Then
        selectedCol = "B"
    Else
        selectedCol = "C"
    End If
    ' Frame 3 values
    Dim doAllSheets As Boolean
    doAllSheets = Me.OptionButton4.Value
    'Frame 4 values
    Dim sheetsToExcludeList As String
    If Me.CheckBox1.Value Then sheetsToExcludeList = sheetsToExcludeList & ",Cover"
    If Me.CheckBox2.Value Then sheetsToExcludeList = sheetsToExcludeList & ",Trans_Letter"
    If Me.CheckBox3.Value Then sheetsToExcludeList = sheetsToExcludeList & ",Abbreviations"
    If Me.CheckBox4.Value Then sheetsToExcludeList = sheetsToExcludeList & ",Index"
    ' Resizing
    Dim shtrng As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    If doAllSheets Then
        ' Loop through sheets
        For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            ' Check sheet name isn't on exclude list
            If InStr(sheetsToExcludeList, "," & sht.Name) = 0 Then
                ' Set range equal to intersection of used range and columns "selected column" onwards
                Set shtrng = Intersect(sht.UsedRange, sht.Range(sht.Cells(1, selectedCol), sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count)).EntireColumn)
                ' Resize columns / rows
                resizerowscols rng:=shtrng, w:=colwidth, h:=rowheight
            End If
        Next sht
    Else
        ' Just active sheet
        Set sht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        Set shtrng = Intersect(sht.UsedRange, sht.Range(sht.Cells(1, selectedCol), sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count)).EntireColumn)
        resizerowscols rng:=shtrng, w:=colwidth, h:=rowheight
    End If
End Sub
```

---

This is the adapted Sub from your other question, but now it takes the range, height and width as arguments. It unhides all rows/columns, resizes them, and re-hides all those which already were.

```
Sub resizerowscols(rng As Range, w As Double, h As Double)
' Resizes all rows and columns, including those which are hidden.
' At the end, hidden rows and columns remain hidden.
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim n As Long
    Dim hiddencols() As Long
    Dim hiddenrows() As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Get hidden rows/cols
    ReDim hiddencols(rng.Columns.Count)
    ReDim hiddenrows(rng.Rows.Count)
    For n = 0 To UBound(hiddencols)
        hiddencols(n) = rng.Columns(n + 1).Hidden
    Next n
    For n = 0 To UBound(hiddenrows)
        hiddenrows(n) = rng.Rows(n + 1).Hidden
    Next n
    ' Unhide all
    rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    rng.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ' resize all
    rng.ColumnWidth = w
    rng.rowheight = h
    ' Re-hide rows/cols
    For n = 0 To UBound(hiddencols)
        rng.Columns(n + 1).Hidden = hiddencols(n)
    Next n
    For n = 0 To UBound(hiddenrows)
        rng.Rows(n + 1).Hidden = hiddenrows(n)
    Next n
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: what range are you passing into the sub? For instance, what does `rng.Address` give? In this form of the sub (as opposed to on your other question), you must pass the range into the sub from the user form

Comment: I'm asking how are you calling it? In my example, I call it on this line: `resizerowscols rng:=shtrng, w:=colwidth, h:=rowheight`, where I'm giving it the Range object `shtrng`, which I've already set up.

Comment: yes thats what I did I havent modified your code just copy pasted it, do you want me to edit my [post and copy paste what I have written

Comment: Try adding `If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` (like I just have) at the start of the second sub. The reason I use `Intersect` is to use the columns after the one selected, but only within the `UsedRange`, so it is not running on all the cells, just the used range. Resizing the columns of 50 sheets won't be quick... You could speed things up by putting the `Application.ScreenUpdating` wrapper in the first function, not the second (so it's just called once).

Comment: Sure currently its running once its done I will surely do it

Comment: Thanks for working this out however there are few things which I would like to highlight : when I am changing the row height and column width for columns it is taking the used range however for rows it it is changing for all the rows in the entire sheet

Comment: Second I wanted to change the row height from row 7 onwards so as suggested I modified the code to  Set shtrng = Intersect(sht.UsedRange, sht.Range(sht.Cells(7, selectedCol), sht.Cells(7, sht.Columns.Count)).EntireColumn)

Comment: but its still changing it from row 1

Comment: I have edited the code please suggest if I am doing anything wrong

Comment: Again, don't edit your question to completely change its meaning. By all means edit to **add** information, but try not to completely replace your code. It is still going from row 1 because of the `EntireColumn` command, instead use `Intersect(sht.UsedRange, sht.Range(sht.Cells(7, selectedCol), sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, sht.Columns.Count)))`. If you still have issues, try with a really simple range (like `sht.Range("B7:E12")`) and debug, then make it progressively more complex. If issues still persist, ask another question if the original question here is now answered :)