# Change column width and row height of hidden columns and rows (remaining hidden): Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which changes column width and row height of all the worksheets in my excel workbook, however, this macro is not making the changes in the hidden rows and column.

Please suggest how should I modify my code so that it should change the column width and row height of hidden rows and columns and keep them hidden?

```
Sub rowcolactivesheetb()

    Dim exworkb As Workbook
    Dim xlwksht As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow1 As Long
    Dim lastcolumn1 As Long
    Dim firstrowDB As Long

    With ActiveSheet

        lastrow1 = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lastcolumn1 = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastrow1, lastcolumn1)).Select

        With Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            .ColumnWidth = 10.2
            .RowHeight = 9.4
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

---

**Edit**

I have implemented Wolfie's method below, but am now getting

> Run-time error 91, Object variable or With block variable not set.

on this line:

```
' Z is a number, my loop variable for looping over each sheet
rng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Z).Range(Sheets(Z).Cells(1, 3), Sheets(Z).Cells(lastrow1, lastcolumn1))
```

Comment: If you edit a hidden row and column they will become visible so you need to hide them again

Comment: Thats the main problem can it be hidden automatically by applying any code that it changes the row width and height and becomes hidden again

Comment: In my excel sheet apart from hidden rows and columns there are grouped rows and columns as well if is it possible to modify my code that it works for the grouped rows and columns (if not hidden rows and columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is fairly straight-forward, and commented for further details. Steps:

- Loop through rows and columns in the used range, note which ones are hidden.
- Unhide everything and resize
- Loop back through rows and columns, hiding those which were hidden before

**Code**:

```
Sub rowcolactivesheetb()
' Resizes all rows and columns, including those which are hidden.
' At the end, hidden rows and columns remain hidden.
    Dim n As Long
    Dim hiddencols() As Long
    Dim hiddenrows() As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        ' Set up range variable and true/false hidden arrays        
        ' We don't need to find last row/col, just used UsedRange
        Set rng = .UsedRange
        ReDim hiddencols(rng.Columns.Count)
        ReDim hiddenrows(rng.Rows.Count)
        ' Get hidden/visible status of each row and column
        For n = 0 To UBound(hiddencols)
            hiddencols(n) = rng.Columns(n + 1).Hidden
        Next n
        For n = 0 To UBound(hiddenrows)
            hiddenrows(n) = rng.Rows(n + 1).Hidden
        Next n
        ' Unhide all
        rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        rng.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ' resize all
        rng.ColumnWidth = 10.2
        rng.RowHeight = 9.4
        ' Re-hide rows/cols
        For n = 0 To UBound(hiddencols)
            rng.Columns(n + 1).Hidden = hiddencols(n)
        Next n
        For n = 0 To UBound(hiddenrows)
            rng.Rows(n + 1).Hidden = hiddenrows(n)
        Next n
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

Lastly a note on `With`, you should not start a second `With` block unless it is for an object *within* the first one. But really you could have ditched the (undesirable) `Select` using that fact anyway...

```
With ActiveSheet
    lastrow1 = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastcolumn1 = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastrow1, lastcolumn1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .ColumnWidth = 10.2
        .RowHeight = 9.4
    End With
End With
```

---

Edit:

With respect to your follow up error, you must use the `Set` command when assigning a `Range` object to a variable. So your code should be

```
Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Range("...
```

You don't have to use `Set` for fundamental variable types (Strings, Integers, etc)

Comment: thanks for solving the issue it working on the activesheet but when I modify the code to work on all the worksheets in the workbook then its giving error. I have modified my code

Comment: As I want to change the column width from column C so have modified it accordingly but giving error

Comment: @Stacey You should not edit your post to completely change your original code, otherwise my answer seems obsolete and your original question is lost! You must use the `Set` keyword when assigning a range, so `Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Range("...`. Please consider marking this answer as accepted if it solves your problem.

Comment: @Stacey I have rolled back your question and edited it to demonstrate how you should do it in future, take note! :) I will edit my own answer to address your issue, you don't need to make a new post unless you have further problems.

Comment: Thanks really appreciate it